# How to make the size of View the same as the size of my custom TextureVIew Android

Tags: android, xml

I have code:

```
<FrameLayout
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
  android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
  android:background="#000000"
  android:id="@+id/frame">
    <View
      android:id="@+id/tapView"
      android:background="#0000ff"
      android:layout_height="fill_parent"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"/>
    <com.example.yApp.MyTextureView
      android:id="@+id/texture"
      android:background="#ff0000"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</FrameLayout>
<FrameLayout
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
      android:layout_alignParentStart="true">
<--- some code --->
</FrameLayout>
```

My custom TextureView choose size by code, I need another View (id="tapView") with the same width and height as my custom TextureView and also on the same place on screen.

The problem of my code is that tapView stretches to the full screen and overlaps next FrameLayout

Comment: Is this your whole layout code?

Comment: @parekhkruti26,no, it is contained in Relative Layout

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use `ConstraintLayout`, both of these view will have

```
 app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" 
 app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
```

The view will have

```
 app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/texture"
 app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/texture"
```

matching your view